# Function Returning Whole Number, not Decimal

Tags: vba, excel, average

I am trying to write a code that looks at a set of data and chooses the set within a date range and finds the average of it.  The issue is that my function returns the whole number rather than the decimal.  I have tried to change my function data type to single, double, and long and none of these have worked. The date list is in column A, and the values I'm trying to average are in column B.  My code:

```
Function MONTHLYAVERAGE(OneDate As Date, TwoDate As Date) As Double

Dim TwoDate_Row As Long

Dim i, j As Integer
LookupColumn = "A"
Dim EndRange As Long

EndRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


    For i = 1 To EndRange
        If Range(LookupColumn & i).Value = TwoDate Then TwoDate_Row = i
    Next i


    For j = TwoDate_Row To 1 Step -1
        If Range(LookupColumn & j).Value = OneDate Then OneDate_Row = j
    Next j

        Dim MyDateRange As Range

            LookupColumn2 = "B"

            Set MyDateRange = Range(LookupColumn2 & OneDate_Row & ":" & LookupColumn2 & TwoDate_Row)

        MONTHLYAVERAGE = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(MyDateRange), Standard)

End Function
```

Comment: `Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(MyDateRange), Standard)`- What is `Standard` ?

Comment: Two things here could you please create a messagebox and provide the result of the below line

MONTHLYAVERAGE = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(MyDateRange), Standard), Also replace the Standard with "0.00"

Comment: [Please refer to this article regarding the second argument for `Format`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Comment: Worked for me, after declaring all the variables.`"Standard"` returned `84.1`.  Definition of Standard is:  _Displays the thousand separators, at least one digit to the left of the decimal place, and two digits to the right of the decimal place._

Comment: Did you mean to use `"Standard"` (string literal) by any chance?

Comment: Why do you need to use Format?  The Average function returns a Double, exactly what your function needs to return.

Comment: If you're calling the function from other code - is the variable that receives the figures declared as a double?  If it's a long/integer it will lose the decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rewrite your code, you could use `FIND` to get the row numbers you're after.

```
Public Function MonthlyAverage(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, Optional ColOffSet As Long = 1) As Double

    Dim rFirstCell As Range, rLastCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        'Find first instance of StartDate.
        Set rFirstCell = .Find(StartDate, , , , xlByRows, xlNext)
        If Not rFirstCell Is Nothing Then
            'Find last instance of EndDate.
            Set rLastCell = .Find(EndDate, , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            'Both dates have been found, so we can calculate the average.
            If Not rLastCell Is Nothing Then
                MonthlyAverage = WorksheetFunction.Average(rFirstCell.Resize(rLastCell.Row - rFirstCell.Row + 1).Offset(, 1))
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

You can call the code as:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim TheAnswer As Double
    TheAnswer = MonthlyAverage(CDate("01/02/2017"), CDate("01/03/2017"))

    MsgBox TheAnswer

End Sub
```

If you declare `TheAnswer` as a double it gives, for me at least, the result of `84.1034482758621`, if I declare it as a long it returns `84`.

**Now, another way of doing it without VBA:**
If your dates are in column A, and your figures are in column B.
Enter the required start date in cell `E2`, and the required end date in cell `E3` and use this formula:
`=AVERAGE(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($E$2,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($E$3,$A:$A,0)+COUNTIF($A:$A,$E$3)-1))`

If there are only unique dates you can remove the `+COUNTIF($A:$A,$E$3)-1)` part.